# Multiple scene on multiple canvas Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created two scenes on two different canvases:

```
var scene1 = new THREE.Scene()
var scene2 = new THREE.Scene()
scene1.add(camera1)
scene2.add(camera2)
```

next i have created two renders with "autoClear: false" :

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true});
renderer.autoClear = false;
$obj3D[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);

renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true});
renderer2.autoClear = false;
$obj3D2[0].appendChild(renderer2.domElement);
```

Now in update function i do (with renderer.clear() and renderer.clearDepth()) :

```
function update() {
    controls.update();
    controls2.update();

    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.clearDepth();

    renderer2.clear();
    renderer2.render(scene2, camera2);
    renderer2.clearDepth();
}
```

But in this way it only shows the object on the last canvas.
Where am I wrong? I do not understand

Here there is the demo: http://atktest.000webhostapp.com/,
Here there is the code: https://github.com/ab89/3d

**I explain better what I want to do:**

I need to create a page that shows up to 5 identical objects.
That is, I load the .obj only once but then I will go to customize them.
I tried to do it but only shows me the last one.

I did it this way because the way I know to change the material of the object is this:

```
OBJ.traverse (function (child) {

             if (child.name! == '') {
                 console.log (child)
                 var clone_material = child.material [0] .clone ();
                 clone_material.map = texture;
                 child.material = clone_material;
             }
         });

         scene.add (OBJ);
```

so i thought i need to have more scenes to do it.
But I should also have: OBJ2, OBJ3, OBJ4, OBJ5 to do the 'traverse' function
and change the texture of each object

Comment: You need to post the relevant code *in the question itself*.

Comment: Did you clone `OBJ` itself?  `OBJ2 = OBJ.clone(); OBJ2.traverse(...)`

Comment: yes, and how can I make it change to only one object viewed? Do I have to create two scenes?

Comment: is so difficult?